# How can I add up two randomly generated numbers inclusively? Java

Tags: java, addition

I'm asking the user to enter two random numbers(i.e 1 10) then I have to add them up inclusively, so (1 10) would be 55.

```
public int sum(int num1, int num2) {

    int counter; //just a variable until I clean this up and get it to work
    questions++;

    if (num1 < num2) {
        int difference = num2-num1;//difference between the   given numbers
        int holder = 0;
            while (holder <= difference) {
                holder ++;
                num1 += num1;
            }
        counter = num1;
    }
}
```

This is the chunk of code I have been testing. This gives me 256 when I run 1 and 10.

Comment: `javascript != java` remove the javascript if the code was only java

Comment: By adding `num1` to itself you'll be getting values of `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...`, doubling each time all the way up to `256`. You need separate variables for the running total and the amount to add each time. As an aside I suspect you want `if (num1 <= num2) {` so that `sum(10, 10)` would be `10`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (num1 < num2)
    {
        int answer = num1;
            while (num1 <= num2)
            {
                answer = answer + num1++;
            }
       retrun answer;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 variant:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(Math.min(num1, num2), Math.max(num2, num1)).sum()
```

What it does:

1. Create range of ints that contains all numbers from num1 to num2 inclusively

   - we need to make sure that left border always less than right one, otherwise range will be empty. That's why I've used `min()` and `max()`
2. Add all the numbers together.

Beware though:
Certain combinations of numbers produce a sum that's higher than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, and this will cause the sum to overflow and possibly produce negative values.
This can be accounted for by using slightly different version, that's slightly less performant:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(Math.min(num1, num2), Math.max(num2, num1))
  .mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf)
  .reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger::add);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int sum(int num1, int num2) {
    int result = 0;
    while(num1<=num2) {
        System.out.println("num1 is: "+num1);
        result = result + num1;
        num1++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Please note the print line within the loop to display the progress of the while.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're doing this as a programming exercise, so using a loop is the whole point of the task. However, if you just wanted code that gave you the right answer you could use the **arithmetic series** formula:

```
public int sum(int num1, int num2) {
    if (num1 <= num2) {
        return (num2 - num1 + 1) * (num1 + num2) / 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```